# Rails Heroku SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, getaddrinfo, geokit

I am on a heroku app, Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.0.12 and using the geokit-rails gem.

When I do a `IpGeocoder.geocode(request.remote_ip)` I get the error:

```
Caught an error during Ip geocoding call: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

I searched online and found that the solution is to make an initialiser and require a library:

```
require 'resolv-replace'
```

When I do so I get the error:

```
Caught an error during Ip geocoding call: Hostname not known: api.hostip.info
```

I am not sure what I should do then. On my development machine works fine. Any clue what the issue is?

Comment: make sure it is not an internet issue; normally we see this error when internet is disconnected

Comment: Followed this through UpWork. I think some thing is blocking the app connecting to the internet. Are you on Linux?

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen The issue is only on production at Heroku. In the past I did the same implementation on Digital Ocean and it worked fine. Yes both DO and Heroku was on linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku uses forwarding, that causes `request.remote_ip` return internal heroku ip address, which cannot be processed by IpGeocoder for some reason.

Try to use `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` insted.